# Put an execute command inside another execute command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to put a "double conditional" in a command block (two execute commands in the same command), like so:

```
/execute foo run execute bar run command
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes but why?  There isn't much reason to do this, other than to change the execution context.

Comment: Related question: [In what order are parameters in /execute calculated? Does the order we type them in matter?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/370684/250180)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, a `/execute` command with multiple parameters remains functionally the same if you add the words `run execute` in between each parameter.

For example, these two are equivalent:

```
/execute as @p at @s if entity @p[distance=..10] run say Hi!
/execute as @p run execute at @s run execute if entity @p[distance=..10] run say Hi!
```

Therefore, there is no need to place multiple `/execute` commands within each other. It remains the same putting all the parameters in one command.

For your double conditional, all you need to do is include multiple `if`/`unless` parameters:

```
/execute if entity @p[tag=tagA] if entity @p[tag=tagB] run say hello worl
```